# Fortan code for Monte Carlo Integration within boundary point a and b

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran77

I understand Monte carlo simulation is for estimating area by plotting random points and calculating the ration between the points outside the curve and inside the curve.

I have well calculated the value of pi assuming radius of curve to be unity.

Here is the code

```
program pi
implicit none

integer :: count, n, i
real :: r, x, y
count = 0
n=500
CALL RANDOM_SEED
DO i = 1, n
 CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
 CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(y)
 IF (x*x + y*Y <1.0) count = count + 1
END DO
r = 4 * REAL(count)/n
print *, r
end program pi
```

But to find integration , Textbook says to apply same idea. But I'm lost on How to write a code if I want to find the integration of

```
f(x)=sqrt(1+x**2) over a = 1 and b = 5
```

Before when radius was one, I did assume point falling inside by condition x*2+y**2 but How can I solve above one?[image]

Any help is extremely helpful

Comment: One interpretation of an integral is that it is the area between a curve, the x-axis, and the limits of integration (1 and 5 in your case).  So your task becomes one of generating points and testing whether or not they are inside that area, which has 3 straight sides and one curved side.  It becomes a little more difficult if the function you are integrating crosses the x-axis between the limits, but I don't think yours does.  Draw a sketch, scratch your head, then the code is relatively straightforward.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for response....I am just starting to understand about fortran as it was introduced as your compulary subject in master program. I well understand trapezoidal, simson, newton rhapson and bisection method and also monte carlo part for getting pi...but on getting this ...I am struggling for past 3 hours......It is out of my league...can you please help..I will further learn by structure of program and develop my own then.....

Comment: The time between my comment and yours suggests you didn't spend very long following the advice in the last sentence of my comment.  Beyond that, no, I'm not willing to answer this question, the comment is all the help I can give you right now.  I expect someone with  more time than I have, and perhaps a more generous nature, will come along soon and write your code for you.  Just be patient, it's only 15 minutes since you asked your question and there aren't many Fortran watchers here on SO.

Comment: This is very similar to computing a pi using Monte Carlo, actually. Draw yourself a graph of the function on the interval to see more.

Comment: @VladimirF The text book also says same that the same idea applies here . I understand the problem when It is between 0 and 1 where I can apply condition of (y<=f(x)) count = count+1    but when it is between any two interval other then 0 and 1 ...I am strugglig to figure out of it's solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will write the code first and then explain:

```
Program integral
implicit none
real f
integer, parameter:: a=1, b=5, Nmc=10000000   !a the lower bound, b the upper bound, Nmc the size of the sampling (the higher, the more accurate the result)
real:: x, SUM=0

do i=1,Nmc                  !Starting MC sampling
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(x)     !generating random number x in range [0,1]
  x=a+x*(b-a)               !converting x to be in range [a,b]
  SUM=SUM+f(x)              !summing all values of f(x). EDIT: SUM is also an instrinsic function in Fortran so don't call your variable this, I named it so, to illustrate its purpose
enddo

print*, (b-a)*(SUM/Nmc)     !final result of your integral
end program integral

function f(x)           !defining your function
  implicit none
  real, intent(in):: x
  real:: f

  f=sqrt(1+x**2)
end function f
```

So what's happening:

The integral  [image: integ] can be written as 
[image: integ2]. where:

[image: g(x)]

(this g(x) is a uniform probability distribution of the variable x in [a,b]). And we can write the integral as:

[image: inter3]

where [image: this].

So, finally, we get that the integral should be:

[image: final]

So, all you have to do is generate a random number in the range [a,b] and then calcualte the value of your function for this x. Then do this lots of times (Nmc times), and calculate the sum. Then just divide with Nmc, to find the average and then multiply with (b-a). And this is what the code does.

There's lots of stuff on the internet for this. [here's](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/monte-carlo-methods-in-practice/monte-carlo-integration) one example that visualizes it pretty nice

EDIT: Second way, that is the same as the Pi method:

```
Nin=0                    !Number of points inside the function (under the curve)
do i=1,Nmc
  call random_number(x)
  call random_number(y)
  x=a+x*(b-a)
  y=f_min+y(f_max-f_min)
  if (f(x)<y) Nin=Nin+1
enddo
print*, (f_max-f_min)*(b-a)*(real(Nin)/Nmc)
```

All of this, you could then enclose it in an outer do loop summing the (f_max-f_min)*(b-a)*(real(Nin)/Nmc) and in the end printing its average.
For this example, what you do is essentially creating an enclosing box from a to b (x dimension) and from f_min to f_max (y dimension) and then doing a sampling of points inside this area and counting the points that are in the function (Nin).Obviously you will have to know the minimum (f_min) and maximum (f_max) value of your function in the range [a,b]. Alternatively you could use arbitrarily low/high values for your f_min f_max but then you will be wasting a lot of points and your error will be bigger.

Comment: Even better would be to define `x` to be an array and to call `random_number(x)`, this is usually appreciably faster than acquiring the same number of random numbers one at a time.  It's probably better not to advise beginners to use the name of an intrinsic function (eg `SUM`) as the name of a variable, especially so where `SUM` could be used to sum the values of a result array.  And leaving `f` external to the program, rather than either internal or use-associated, is not best practice these days.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You are right about SUM, I edited my answer. I just wanted to be clear on what each variable does. As for the function, if it were my (bigger) program I would probably stuck it in a module and use the module or use an interface. I just wanted to give a clean example, not really focusing on the programming details of it, you are right to point this out of course.

Comment: (character limit reached:) As for the random number generation, I did a test and it doesn't seem like `call random_number(x)` (x an array) is faster than calling it N times for a variable x. 0.484s for the do loop, 1.68s for the array (for N=100000000). Plus, if you set x as an array you start having problems with big sizes and then you have to use allocatable array, which isn't something complicated, but again wouldn't want him to focus on other things other than the MC sampling.

Comment: Hmm, interesting data you report, counter to my own recent experiences.  Yes, big arrays might be a problem, but `10^9` (?) samples might be overkill anyway.